# Change the color of button ( appears) in button properties when button has ripple effect

Tags: android, xml

I want to change the color of button. Let's say: Blue. How can we add color of button in `ripple.xml` file that is actually the properties of button? From the code below the color of button is transparent.

**Button in content_main.xml**

```
  <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
```

**ripple.xml**

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="#f816a463"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#f816a463" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

**Edit1**

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="#16a463"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#16a463" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Comment: use `#16a463` six digit for the color. 8 digit included color with transparent of color .

Comment: @sushildlh Where to add background color?

Comment: in the ripple.xml `android:color="#16a463"` use here blue color code in 6 digit only ....

Comment: @sushildlh But it is not changing the background color. It is still transparent. See the **edit1**

Comment: have look on answer ......

Answer (score 1):

**Problem is `android:id="@android:id/mask"` . i think it provide the custom value of android.**

try this one .....

```
      <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" />
</ripple>
```

output:-

[image]

You have to use the Selector for this animation....

> anim.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ripple"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal"/>
</selector>
```

and set you default color in `button_normal.xml` .....

and set `anim.xml` in your button background .....

**NOTE:- Ripple is working on API level 21 and above .......**

Comment: Nice catch, what is the point to set an id in a drawable layout in the first place ?

Comment: i don't have enough idea about that ..... @AxelH please share if you find the  point ....

Comment: @sushildlh The ripple effect is not working in your code now. Just its button color. Nothing happening when click the button.

Comment: try this http://guides.codepath.com/android/ripple-animation it solve all your doubt ....

Answer (score 0):

ripple_drawable.xml //place this in drawable-v21 folder

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
                      android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
        <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="@color/your_color" />
            </shape>
        </item>
 </ripple>
```

Note : ripple effect will only work on android 5.0 and above

Comment: It is not changing the colorrrrrrrrrrrrrr of button.

Comment: which version of android are you testing??

Comment: I want to change the color of button. As i clicked on the button it is going to gray type color. But the button is still white. I change the button color.

Comment: @Humty please answer for the above comment,  Have you placed the xml file in drawable-v21 folder??

Comment: Yes I did! It is not changing the button color.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question is, you want to change the color, right ?
Just change the value of `<solid android:color="#f816a463"` in `ripple.xml`

```
F816A463
```

first two digits of color `F8` means the opacity, if you want to solid color, please remove the first two digits eg : `#ff1122`

Comment: I hope to think that this wasn't working as it is in his question (but I could be surprised..)

Answer (score 0):

if your intention is only to set the background color of the button the try this in `onCreate` method after initializing the your button

```
Button yourBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yout_btn_id);
yourBtn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color));
```

and define the `your_color` value resource in your `color.xml` file under values folder